# Display Coupon usage limit Number with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

i did a coupon in woocommerce with a limit usage of 150,

And i would like to get the number of remaining coupons in my homepage with a shortcode.

Like if my coupon is "Coupon-test" with 150 limit usage, when i do a [coupon-test] in my homepage it return  150, if there's an order it will change to 149 etc...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add following code in the short code

```
$coupon_code = 'Coupon-test';
global $woocommerce;
$coupon_data = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
echo ($coupon_data->usage_limit - $coupon_data->usage_count);// return number of remaining coupons
```